# Telling me what lesson I have tomorrow and emailing me the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

This program tells me what lessons I have tomorrow then emails them to me.

This program works fine, but I was wondering whether there is a way to simplify the script or make it more efficient. I have removed my email and password and who it is to for privacy, but it does work.

```
import smtplib
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date

days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
English = ["MondayA", "WednesdayA", "ThursdayA", "FridayA", "TuesdayB", "WednesdayB", "ThursdayB"]
Maths = ["MondayA", "TuesdayA", "WednesdayA", "ThursdayA", "FridayA", "TuesdayA", "FridayB"]
Bioligy = []    #I will fill the following three
Physics = []
Chemistry = []
Computing = ["TuesdayA", "WednesdayA", "ThursdayA", "WednesdayB", "ThursdayB"]
History = ["MondayA", "TuesdayA", "MondayB", "TuesdayB", "WednesdayB"]
PE = ["ThursdayA", "WednesdayB", "FridayB"]
BaV = ["TuesdayA", "FridayB"]
French = ["MondayA", "FridayA", "MondayB", "TuesdayB", "FridayB"]
Course42 = ["MondayB"]
lesson = []
Comma = (", ")

day1 = (datetime.datetime.today().weekday())
day = (days[day1 + 1])

def WeekA(a):
    Oday = (a + "A")

    if Oday in English:
        lesson.append("English")

    if Oday in Maths:
        lesson.append("Maths")

    if Oday in Bioligy:
        lesson.append("Bioligy")

    if Oday in Physics:
        lesson.append("Physics")

    if Oday in Chemistry:
        lesson.append("Chemistry")

    if Oday in Computing:
        lesson.append("Computing")

    if Oday in History:
        lesson.append("History")

    if Oday in PE:
        lesson.append("PE")

    if Oday in BaV:
        lesson.append("B&V")

    if Oday in French:
        lesson.append("French")

    if Oday in Course42:
        lesson.append("Course42")

def WeekB(b):
    Oday = (b + "B")

    if Oday in English:
        lesson.append("English")

    if Oday in Maths:
        lesson.append("Maths")

    if Oday in Bioligy:
        lesson.append("Bioligy")

    if Oday in Physics:
        lesson.append("Physics")

    if Oday in Chemistry:
        lesson.append("Chemistry")

    if Oday in Computing:
        lesson.append("Computing")

    if Oday in History:
        lesson.append("History")

    if Oday in PE:
        lesson.append("PE")

    if Oday in BaV:
        lesson.append("B&V")

    if Oday in French:
        lesson.append("French")

    if Oday in Course42:
        lesson.append("Course42")


WeekA(day)



content = ("You have " + Comma.join(lesson) + ".")

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login('*email*','*password*')

mail.sendmail('*email*','*email*', content)

mail.close()
```

Comment: does `Oday` stand for `today`? Why is it used before it is defined?

Answer (score 13):

I would change the data organization to be the opposite way, to have a dict mapping to the two week types containing a dict with a mapping from the weekday to the lessons:

```
timetable = {"A": {"Monday": ["English", "Maths", ...],
                   "Tuesday": ["Maths", "Computing", ...],
                   ...},
             "B": {"Monday": ["History", ...],
                   ...}}
```

*By the way, it is spelled `Biology`, not `Bioligy`.*

Then you can just use it like this:

```
import smtplib
import datetime

TIMETABLE = {"A": [["English", "Maths", ...],
                   ["Maths", "Computing", ...],
                   ...],
             "B": [["History", ...],
                   ...]}

SEMESTER_START = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1)


def calculate_week_type(date, start_date):
    """Even weeks since start_date are "A" weeks, uneven are "B" weeks"""
    return "A" if ((date-start_date).days / 7) % 2 == 0 else "B"

def lessons(timetable, start_date, date):
    week_type = calculate_week_type(date, start_date)
    return timetable[week_type][date.weekday()]

def mail_lessons(lessons, to_email='*email*'):
    content = "You have {} today.".format(", ".join(lessons))
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('*email*', '*password*')
    mail.sendmail('*email*', to_email, content)
    mail.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    mail_lessons(lessons(TIMETABLE, SEMESTER_START, today))
```

I put the different responsibilities into separate functions, got rid of most of the global variables, and fixed some small differences to PEP8, python's official style-guide. I used a `format` string, because it is in general faster than string addition (it is usually more readable as well).

I also made the mapping now using numerical weekdays as indices into the internal list of lists, because this is what `datetime` returns. This way there is no need to translate between the two.

Answer (score 2):

I would add all the classes into an dictionary

```
Courses = {
    English : ["MondayA", "WednesdayA", "ThursdayA", "FridayA", "TuesdayB", "WednesdayB", "ThursdayB"]
...
,   Course42 : ["MondayB"]
}
```

then turn your current two functions into one with another argument (also have a sensible name for them) and loop over the dictionary putting the key of any array that contains the current day to be tested

```
def Week( weekday, whichWeek ):
    testDay = weekday + whichWeek
    for course, days in courses.items():
        if testDay in days:
            lesson.append( course )
```

also instead of calling `,` 'Comma' I would use 'Separator'

Comment: `also instead of calling , 'Comma' I would use 'Separator'` Definitely. It's akin to a [magic number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). One day comma may not be `,` and it'll just look odd to read.